# Get InnerHTMLof JS from Website using Java

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, nashorn

Goal: Get inner text of JavaScript element from Yahoo Finance Page.  Please refer to

[image]

I can get the innerHTML using the the code below

```
document.getElementsByClassName('D(ib) Va(t)')[15].childNodes[2].innerHTML
```

But, I can't find a method to communicate this to the Yahoo Finance page in Java

I've briefly tried the following APIs:

- JSoup
- HTMLUnit
- Nashorn

I think Nashorn can get the text I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to do it yet.

If anyone has done something similar or can point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: What goes wrong with JSoup? Nashorn is just a JS engine for the JVM so I'm not sure what you're trying to say with all that.

Comment: Jsoup only returns the html of the page.  Here is the code I used for Jsoup:   Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL").get();
   Elements parsedInfo = doc.getElementsByClass("'D(ib) Va(t)"); 
   String myInfo = parsed.text(); 
   System.out.println(doc);

Comment: I think, you should modify your question from technical point of view. You should understand difference between JavaScript and HTML. The element you are talking about is HTML element, JavaScript doesn't have elements. Well if you have HTML/XML, you can parse it in Java using SAX parser, and get the data you want to fetch. NOTE:- SAX parser is not intended for huge XML/HTML. So for this, you have to use DOM parser.

Comment: The content is generated/populated dynamically using javascript, so DOM parser alone won't help here (that is why JSoup also fails here). HTMLUnit contains a javascript engine (rhino, predecessor to nashorn), but in my tests, it often failed to fully load dynamic pages. Nashorn is a js engine but not a headless browser (https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlUnit seems to have problems with this site, since the response is incomplete as well. You could use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Just [download the binary](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) for your OS and create a script file (see [API](http://phantomjs.org/api/)).

**Script** (`yahoo.js`):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.resourceTimeout = '5000';



page.open('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {

    var path = 'yahoo.html';
    fs.write(path, page.content, 'w');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

**Java code**:

```
try {
    //change path to phantomjs binary and your script file
    String phantomJSPath = "bin" + File.separator + "phantomjs";
    String scriptFile = "yahoo.js";

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(phantomJSPath + " " + scriptFile);
    process.waitFor();

    //Jsoup
    Elements elements = Jsoup.parse(new File("yahoo.html"),"UTF-8").select("div.asset-profile-container p strong"); //yahoo.html created by script file in same path

    for (Element element : elements) {
        if(element.attr("data-reactid").contains("asset-profile.1.1.1.2")){
            System.out.println(element.text());
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output**:

```
Consumer Goods
```

---

*Note:*
The following link returns a JSONObject containing the company information, not sure though if the `crumb` parameter changes or is constant for a company:
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL?formatted=true&crumb=hm4%2FV0JtzlL&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=assetProfile%2CsecFilings%2CcalendarEvents&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com

Comment: It worked!  Thank you so much.  I spent the better part of my Sunday trying to figure out how to get those two words.  It means a lot, I was about to give on that part of my project.